# Java split a paragraph by periods

Tags: java

I'm trying to build up a regular expression which splits a paragraph in sentences separated by a period (`.`). That should work:

```
String str[] = text.split("\\.");
```

However I'd need to add a minimum of robustness, for example checking that the period is followed by a `space` and an uppercase letter.
So here's my next guess:

```
String text="The pen is on the table. The table has a pen upon it.";
String arr[] = text.split("\\. [A-Z]");

for (String s: arr)
    System.out.println(s);

Output:
The pen is on the table
he table has a pen upon it.
```

Unfortunately, I'm missing the first character after the period. Can you see any way it can be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to see what is coming next in the string.

```
text.split("\\. (?=[A-Z])");
{ "The pen is on the table", "The table has a pen upon it." }
```

If you want to keep the periods as well, you can also use a lookbehind:

```
text.split("(?<=\\.) (?=[A-Z])");
{ "The pen is on the table.", "The table has a pen upon it." }
```